# Some of my button click buttons don't work in C# for Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a very basic calculator in Visual Studio to learn how to code a Windows Application using C#. However, I am running into an issue where some of my Button click methods don't do anything when I click them. My code for the window is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string displayContent;
        static string operation = "";
        static double firstNumber, secondNumber;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            double temp = 0.0;
            displayContent = temp.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(displayContent);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("8");
        }

        private void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetDisplay("0");
        }

        public void SetDisplay(string text)
        {
            displayContent = text;
            DisplayOutput.Content = text;
        }

        public void AddToDisplay(string text)
        {
            
            if (DisplayOutput.Content.ToString().Equals("0"))
            {
                displayContent = text;
            } else
            {
                displayContent += text;
            }
            DisplayOutput.Content = displayContent;
        }

        public void evaluateEquation()
        {
            string temp = DisplayOutput.Content.ToString();
            if (temp.Contains(".")) //Check for multiple decimals
            {
                int countDecimals = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (temp[i] == '.')
                    {
                        countDecimals++;
                    }
                }
                if (countDecimals > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Syntax Error!");
                    DisplayOutput.Content = "Syntax Error!";
                }
            }
            secondNumber = Double.Parse(temp);
            if (operation.Equals("*"))
            {
                DisplayOutput.Content = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            } else if (operation.Equals("/"))
            {
                DisplayOutput.Content = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            } else if (operation.Equals("+"))
            {
                DisplayOutput.Content = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            } else if (operation.Equals("-"))
            {
                DisplayOutput.Content = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            } else
            {
                DisplayOutput.Content = "0";
            }

        }
        //Operation Buttons
        private void ButtonPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operation = "+";
            firstNumber = Double.Parse(DisplayOutput.Content.ToString());
        }

        private void ButtonMinus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operation = "-";
            firstNumber = Double.Parse(DisplayOutput.Content.ToString());
        }

        private void ButtonMultiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operation = "*";
            firstNumber = Double.Parse(DisplayOutput.Content.ToString());
        }

        private void ButtonDivide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operation = "/";
            firstNumber = Double.Parse(DisplayOutput.Content.ToString());
        }

        //Numbered Buttons
        private void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("7");
        }

        private void Button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => AddToDisplay("8");

        private void Button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("9");
        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("4");
        }

        private void Button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("5");
        }

        private void Button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("6");
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("1");
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("2");
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("3");
        }

        private void Button0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay("0");
        }

        private void ButtonDecimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToDisplay(".");
        }

        private void ButtonEquals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            evaluateEquation();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Calculator" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Basic Calculator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Cooper Black"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonPlus" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonMinus" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonMultiply" Content="x" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonDivide" Content="÷" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonClear" Content="C&#10;L&#10;E&#10;A&#10;R" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="125" FontSize="18" Click="ButtonClear_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button7" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24" Click="Button7_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button8" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button9" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button5" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button6" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button0" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonDecimal" Content="." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonEquals" Content="=" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="24" Click="ButtonEquals_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="DisplayOutput" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Width="600" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Currently only my 7, 8, clear, and enter buttons work as expected, but none of the others do anything when I click on them. Is there something I am doing wrong? I am relatively new with C#, coming from JavaScript and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your buttons are tied to any click events from WPF. You have to add a button click handler to each component for it call your code in C#.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click"/>
```

will call the Button_Click function.